# Comments on a 'PullableView'

Tags: swift, user-interface

I created a view called `PullView` which adds a level of interactivity to UI components. `PullView`s can be pulled sort of like a rubber-band and bounce a little when released. The code for it is fairly simple.

I would like comments on how to improve code structure, performance, etc. if possible.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

/**
    If the view can be pulled (interacted with by the user)

    isPullable set to true by default

    Most applications will call for use as a container.
*/
class PullableView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
        isPullable = true
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, pullable: Bool) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isPullable = pullable
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private struct Keys {
        static var isPullable = "isPullable"
        static var initCenter = "initCenter"
        static var initTouchPos = "initTouchPos"
        static var pullFactor = "pullFactor"
    }

    /**
        The initial center of the view
    */
    private var initCenter: CGPoint {
        get {
            return layer.value(forKey: Keys.initCenter) as? CGPoint ?? CGPoint.zero
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.setValue(value, forKey: Keys.initCenter)
        }
    }

    /**
        The initial position of the users touch
    */
    private var initTouchPos: CGPoint {
        get {
            return layer.value(forKey: Keys.initTouchPos) as? CGPoint ?? CGPoint.zero
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.setValue(value, forKey: Keys.initTouchPos)
        }
    }

    /**
         The reciprocal of the slope of the derivative of the curve describing the displacement.

         A higher pullFactor allows for less pulling.

         pullFactor should be greater than 1.
    */
    var pullFactor: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.value(forKey: Keys.pullFactor) as? CGFloat ?? 3
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.setValue(value, forKey: Keys.pullFactor)
        }
    }

    /**
        If the view can be pulled.
    */
    var isPullable: Bool {
        get {
            return layer.value(forKey: Keys.isPullable) as? Bool ?? false
        }
        set(value) {
            if value { isUserInteractionEnabled = true }
            layer.setValue(value, forKey: Keys.isPullable)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isPullable {
            initCenter = center
            initTouchPos = touches.first!.location(in: superview)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isPullable {
            let loc = touches.first!.location(in: self.superview)
            let xOffset = loc.x - initTouchPos.x
            let yOffset = loc.y - initTouchPos.y
            let xOffsetD = xOffset / pullFactor
            let yOffsetD = yOffset / pullFactor

            center.x = xOffsetD + initCenter.x
            center.y = yOffsetD + initCenter.y
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isPullable {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                self.center = self.initCenter
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```